# function delete dont work in the second time i activate it

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

i have a function that contains delete in it:

```
void Vector::reserve(int n){
    //if there is a need to increase the size of the vector
    if (n > _size){
        int* tampArr;
        //check what the new size of the array should be
        _capacity = n + (n - _capacity) % _resizeFactor;
        tampArr = new int[_capacity];
        //put in the new array the element i have in the curr array
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++){
            tampArr[i] = _elements[i];
        }
        delete[] _elements;
        _elements = NULL;//this 
        //put the new array in _element
        _elements = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++){
            _elements[i] = tampArr[i];
        }
        delete[] tampArr;
    }
}
```

the class field is:

```
private:
    //Fields
    int* _elements;
    int _capacity; //Total memory allocated
    int _size; //Size of vector to access
    int _resizeFactor; // how many cells to add when need to reallocate
```

for some reason the first time i use the function it doesn't show any errors and work perfect but in the second time its stops in the line: "delete[] _elements;" it stops.
in addition when i run this function one time it stops at the end of the object:

```
Vector::~Vector(){
    delete[] _elements;
}
```

can someone help me?

Comment: make sure that `_elements` is set to `NULL` in the constructor, otherwise `reserve` deletes some undefined memory area. to help you further we would need a [mcve]

Comment: I hope you are aware that your final _elements array is of size n and not _capacity.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal thank you. i hate that kind of errors, my eyes just jumped above this line every time...

Comment: @AbhishekBansal this is probably why it fails, yes.

Comment: @YuvalPaz 1) Don't start your name with underscores.  2) Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: More on the above underscore comment: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Those are perfectly valid symbols at class scope. Symbols starting with an underscore are only reserved at global scope.

Answer (score -3):

You don't check that _elements is valid before you delete it.  Assuming you don't set _elements somewhere else, this is a major bug.  Add: `if(_elements) delete[] _elements;`  And also make sure you initialize *_elements to be null before this function is called.

Comment: deleting a nullptr is perfectly legal and well-behaved (does nothing).